# Let $F$ be a field. Find a matrix $A ∈ M_{4×4}(F)$ satisfying $A^4 = I \neq A^3$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $F$ be a field. Find a matrix $A ∈ M_{4×4}(F)$ satisfying $A^4 = I \neq A^3$.

I'm trying to find a simple matrix that explains this, any thoughts?

Comment: If $char(F) \neq 2$, then this seems easy. Try to calculate the eigenvalues of $A$, and then place them on the diagonal

Answer (score 2):

I'll expand my answer. Enough to tackle the problem in $M_{2}F$, for then we can use them as blocks to construct such matrices. For $char(F) \neq 2$, $diag(1,-1)$ works. For $char(F)=2$, the following matrix works -

$$
\pmatrix{1 & 1\\
0 & 1}
$$

Comment: Why not simply $-I$?

Answer (score 2):

Just take $A$ to be the permutation matrix:
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix}
&1& &  \\
& &1&  \\
& & &1 \\
1& & &
\end{pmatrix},
$$
then $A^4=I$, while
$$
A^3=\begin{pmatrix}
&&&1 \\
1&&& \\
&1&& \\
&&1&
\end{pmatrix}\neq I.
$$
This works regardless of the characteristic of $F$.